# ImportError: cannot import name 'ModelFactory' from 'frlearn.base'

Tags: python, importerror, fuzzy-search, viewmodelfactory

I get an error (ImportError: cannot import name 'ModelFactory' from 'frlearn.base') when running the following code:

```
from frlearn.base import ModelFactory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive you are using `frlearn` from this [github repo](https://github.com/oulenz/fuzzy-rough-learn/tree/df25adfa42e81bc3d526602f2a537b626dffae82). You just have to clone this repo using the following command

```
!git clone https://github.com/oulenz/fuzzy-rough-learn.git
```

And then move to the cloned directory using `cd <clonned directory path>`
In your case that may be

```
cd fuzzy-rough-learn
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Right, I'm using frlearn from the Github repo. Have you implemented the code from that Github repo too?

Comment: I have only used frlearn after seeing your question. Glad you resolved your question!!